# How to remove solder mask and paste error in Altium Designer

Tags: altium

Can anyone help me out to remove these errors. From the looks of it they look like solder mask and paste error.

[image]

[image]

Seriously i have tried almost every thing in design rules but don't understand how to remove them. I think they are footprint errors. I have downloaded footprints not created them but will really appreciate if someone could help me to solve these error.

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium resource: https://forum.live.altium.com/

Comment: If you just want to hide the green error marks while you're doing your layout, just go to Tools > Reset Error Markers. If you want to figure out why they're occurring in the first place, you need to run a design rule check (DRC) and figure out what rules are being violated (Tools > Design Rule Check). Without running a DRC, it's going to be difficult for anyone (including you) to identify which specific violations are present.

Comment: @Chris Knudsen Thanks i will have a look there.

Comment: @Cheibriados Well i did and the errors were spacing errors between the solder paste and the solder mask layer and in the first pic its just showing the error but not indicating what is the error. I removed some but some are so persistent that even i make the distance between them a negative digit they don't disappear.